# PyQt QMainwindow call QListWidget from a different file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a problem with PyQt. For several reasons, I have to separate the QListWidget from the main (qt.py) file. When I run my code only the "mainwindow" shows. It's like the list is didn't even called:

*qt.py:*

```
from qt_child import *

class mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,500,500)
        self.lw = ListWidget()

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = mainwindow()   
    
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt Main")
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

*qt_child.py:*

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow, QListWidget

class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300,100)
        self.addItem("Item 1")
        self.addItem("Item 2")
        self.addItem("Item 3")
        self.addItem("Item 4")
```

Comment: Creating a widget does just that, it doesn't show anything. In fact, you're doing `w.show()`, without it the window will never show. Use `self.setCentralWidget(self.lw)`.

Answer (score 1):

change these rows

```
self.lw = ListWidget()
def __init__(self):
super(ListWidget, self).__init__()
```

to

```
self.lw = ListWidget(self)
def __init__(self, parent=None):
super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
```

Comment: While this solution "works", it's officially [unsupported](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) for QMainWindow, as the widget should be set as central widget (or added to a container with a proper layout which will then be set as central widget).